# SingleThreaderDialog.Exception.NoValidMappingDetailsFound

Tags: templates, path, repository, metadata, pentaho

I've moved my .ktr and .kjb files to a repository. In them I use ETL Metadata Injection step, in which I need to specify the transformation to be injected with metadata. Since the files have been moved I had to re-specify transform path. Which I tried to do by using the `Browse` button, upon which the error, `!SingleThreaderDialog.Exception.NoValidMappingDetailsFound!` is thrown:

[image: !SingleThreaderDialog.Exception.NoValidMappingDetailsFound!]

And I am unable to reach my transformation steps to be injected. What am I doing wrong? How can I reconfigure my Transformation path so that it works again?

Tested with:

> `pdi-ce-8.0.0.0-28`

Comment: It may also be related to https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-9152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason one is thrown this error may be because that the files may have been *moved* to the repository as opposed to being *imported* to it. As in it's not enough to move the files using a file manager, as far as [pentaho](/questions/tagged/pentaho) is concerned, those files are ***not*** part of the repository, *even though* <kbd>Browse</kbd> makes them look like they are and they're in the correct folders.

If the file `transformation.ktr` is in fact under `root` folder, then the issue can be solved by adding an additional `\`. As in replace:

```
/transformation
```

with:

```
//transformation
```

---

I've resolved the issue by replacing `/` with `//` in the give path name:

[image: Solution]

Apparently <kbd>Browse</kbd> button doesn't necessarily do that.

---

Make sure to either *import* the files or separately ***save*** them ***as*** they are, *in place*.